# dpkg/ dkms does not exit/ hangs after kernel upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 17.10

I have upgraded to the latest kernel release.

The upgrade process does not finish. When trying manually (on the terminal), I get:

```
Setting up linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic (4.13.0-25.29) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-25-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-25-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-25-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-25-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-25-generic
(hangs)
```

I tried, as suggested in the comments, to remove nvidia drivers and the kernel-image. But this results basically in the same problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic *nvidia*
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic* linux-image-extra-4.13.0-25-generic nvidia-384* nvidia-opencl-icd-384* nvidia-prime*
  nvidia-settings*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 235 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 210977 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.13.0-25-generic (4.13.0-25.29) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-25-generic
(hangs)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me this was connected to the proprietary nvidia drivers (version 385). I removed them using the "Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers" Tab. Afterwards I manually uninstalled the `linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic` package with:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic
```

And ran:

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After a reboot my system was running the newest kernel and I was able to install the newest nvidia drivers.

#### edit:

In case the process is hanging apparently killing the `plymouth` service is supposed to help (See [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1705345)). In a new terminal type

```
sudo pkill plymouth
```

The installation should proceed.

#### edit 2:

As /op mentioned after everything works again reinstall the `linux-image-generic` package to update the kernel to the newest version:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan. But how can I kill the hanging update process? It does not respond to Ctrl-C.

Comment: Use `xkill` from a terminal and click on the program that is running the update (Terminal, Updates or Software Center). Afterwards you might need to delete the  `dpkg` lockfile and / or update files in `/var/lib/dpkg`.

Comment: kill worked. Removing nvidia and also the kernel image will bring me again to the same place. See updated question.

Comment: Question updated. Give `sudo pkill plymouth` a try :)

Comment: Dont forget to reinstall the meta package `linux-image-generic` afterwards, which was removed together with `linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic`. This will also reinstall `linux-image-4.13.0-25-generic`

Comment: Good point! I was already wondering why the package didn't show up anymore as an update. I'll add it to the answer for the sake of completion